# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'video_dataset' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, jupyter, attributeerror

I have a dataset that has been preprocessed, and this error continues to occur.
I've tried the if__name___=='**main**_': method from several communities, but I keep getting errors if I used it incorrectly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\mj\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\mj\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'video_dataset' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

This is how it is defined.

```
class video_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,frame_list,sequence_length = 16,transform = None):
        self.frame_list = frame_list
        self.transform = transform
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.frame_list)
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        label,path = self.frame_list[idx]
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        seq_img = list()
        for i in range(16):
          img1 = img[:,128*i:128*(i+1),:]
          if(self.transform):
            img1 = self.transform(img1)
          seq_img.append(img1)
        seq_image = torch.stack(seq_img)
        seq_image = seq_image.reshape(3,16,im_size,im_size)
        return seq_image,decoder[label]
```

```
import torchvision
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.optim as optim
import copy
import os
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
import cv2
import sys
import import_ipynb
```

This is where the final error occurs.

```
from torch.autograd import Variable
iteration = 0
acc_all = list()
loss_all = list()
    
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print('')
    print(f"--- Epoch {epoch} ---")
    phase1 = dataloaders.keys()
    for phase in phase1:
        print('')
        print(f"--- Phase {phase} ---")
        epoch_metrics = {"loss": [], "acc": []}
        for batch_i, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloaders[phase]):
            #iteration = iteration+1
            image_sequences = Variable(X.to(device), requires_grad=True)
            labels = Variable(y.to(device), requires_grad=False)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            #model.lstm.reset_hidden_state()
            predictions = model(image_sequences)
            loss = cls_criterion(predictions, labels)
            acc = 100 * (predictions.detach().argmax(1) == labels).cpu().numpy().mean()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            epoch_metrics["loss"].append(loss.item())
            epoch_metrics["acc"].append(acc)
            if(phase=='train'):
                lr,mom = onecyc.calc()
                update_lr(optimizer, lr)
                update_mom(optimizer, mom)
            batches_done = epoch * len(dataloaders[phase]) + batch_i
            batches_left = num_epochs * len(dataloaders[phase]) - batches_done
            sys.stdout.write(
                    "\r[Epoch %d/%d] [Batch %d/%d] [Loss: %f (%f), Acc: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)]"
                    % (
                        epoch,
                        num_epochs,
                        batch_i,
                        len(dataloaders[phase]),
                        loss.item(),
                        np.mean(epoch_metrics["loss"]),
                        acc,
                        np.mean(epoch_metrics["acc"]),
                    )
                )

                # Empty cache
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                torch.cuda.empty_cache()
            
        print('')
        print('{} , acc: {}'.format(phase,np.mean(epoch_metrics["acc"])))
        torch.save(model.state_dict(),'weights_crime/c3d_{}.h5'.format(epoch))
        if(phase=='train'):
          acc_all.append(np.mean(epoch_metrics["acc"]))
          loss_all.append(np.mean(epoch_metrics["loss"]))
```

original code is here
https://github.com/sanchit2843/Videoclassification/blob/master/train.ipynb

Comment: it seems you didn't run cell with `class video_dataset():` so later it can't find it. Maybe put all code in one cell.

Comment: That error occurs even when all the codes are combined and rotated. I wrote the wrong code. The original code is this. `class video_dataset(Dataset): `

Comment: did you put `class video_dataset(Dataset)` before other code? Better create minimla working code which we can simply copy because code splited is not useful.

Comment: The class video_dataset (Dataset) code is two thirds, so do you want me to create an class video_dataset.ipynb file and import it?

Comment: I move the class video_dataset (Dataset) part, the execution itself is not possible. and exist Dataset folder. this my orginal code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nT-H_Uwh6rB_fPzvH1HOmu3p_B618FU7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see you first run `train_data = video_dataset(...)` but you define `class video_dataset (Dataset) ` 2 cells later - so you have it in wrong order. You have to define/execute `class video_dataset (Dataset)` before you use `train_data = video_dataset(...)`. But I don't have data to test all code so I don't know if it is the only problem because error shows problem with pickle and subprocessing - so probably it pickle data to send them to subprocesses and these subprocesses may need definition `class video_dataset (Dataset)` to unpickle data.

Comment: do you run this code on local `Jupyter`? Error shows path `"D:\anaconda\...`. But it doesn't look like error in `Jupyter` but in normal script.

Comment: Yes. i run local Jupyter notebook. so you mean that not error?

Comment: If it's not an error, there should be a progression of the training part, but I don't think so.

Comment: When num_workers = 0, it works.

Comment: when you use `num_workers = 0` then you don't use workers and it doesn't have to pickle data to send data to workers and workers don't have to unpickle it  - and workers don't have problem to find definition `class video_dataset(Dataset)` to unpickle it. Workers need definintion `class video_dataset(Dataset)` I never had proble like this but I never run code in Juputer but normally `python script.py`. Problem can be because `Jupyter` may treat every cell as separated script and when it run cell which runs subprocess then it don't have definition `class video_dataset(Dataset)`  in this cell.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue of **AttributeError: Can't get attribute XYZ on <module '**main**' (built-in)>`** and it seems like sometimes it's not about the class that you wrote, but the way you import it. For some reason it does not work with objects not defined in an imported module, especially if you are using notebook. So you have to write your function into a different file and import the module.

Doing so fix the issue for me instantly, hope it helps anyone who stumbles into similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me once.

I was trying to call a dataset in a new script, and this dataset was customized using a **class** and saved on disk.

I fixed it buy adding the **class** that I used for creating dataset to the scripts in which they call the dataset.

In your case I would suggest just copy the class:

```
class video_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,frame_list,sequence_length = 16,transform = None):
        self.frame_list = frame_list
        self.transform = transform
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.frame_list)
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        label,path = self.frame_list[idx]
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        seq_img = list()
        for i in range(16):
          img1 = img[:,128*i:128*(i+1),:]
          if(self.transform):
            img1 = self.transform(img1)
          seq_img.append(img1)
        seq_image = torch.stack(seq_img)
        seq_image = seq_image.reshape(3,16,im_size,im_size)
        return seq_image,decoder[label]
```

then add it to the script in which this erro is occruing.

GL